# NAN Errors when exporting to Unity .fbx

Tags: modeling, .fbx

Among a whole bundle of NaN's, I get this.

```
transform.position assign attempt for 'Preview Scene Camera' is not valid. Input position is { NaN, NaN, NaN }.
UnityEditor.AssetPreviewUpdater:CreatePreviewForAsset(Object, Object[], String)
```

Whatever it is that caused this error is corrupting the sub models as well, I can't get any of them into unity because of these errors.

Comment: Is this an error when importing to unity? Without any more information, we can't help you. Please try to be more specific

Comment: Do you have a question, or is this an attempt at a bug report?

Comment: I created a dress for a character in blender. When importing the .fbx, I receive a large number of NaN errors. 
I'm looking for a way to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are experiencing error (Nann, Nann)96))
To fix this you need to set the rotation of the object to $0,0,0$ and the scale to $1,1,1$ in the modelling tab.